# Getting 400 Status from ASPNET.CORE with AntiforgeryToken

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a angular 4 app with .net core Api. I want to put on some endpoints Antiforgery validation. In this way I managed to get a token in the browser cookies.

This is the startup.cs - Configure:

```
if (env.IsDevelopment())
{
}

app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

app.UseCors("AllowAll");
app.Use(next => context =>
{
    string method = context.Request.Method;
    if (method == "GET")
    {
        var tokens = antiforgery.GetAndStoreTokens(context);
        context.Response.Cookies.Append("XSRF-TOKEN", tokens.RequestToken,
             new CookieOptions()
             {
                 HttpOnly = false,

             });
    }
    return next(context);

});
```

And this is from the ConfigureServices:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme =
                               JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

    options.DefaultChallengeScheme =
                               JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddJwtBearer(o =>
{
    o.Authority = Configuration["IdentityServer"];
    o.Audience = "MyApi";
    o.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

});

services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("AllowAll", builder =>
{
    builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
           .AllowAnyMethod()
           .AllowAnyHeader()
           .AllowCredentials();
}));

services.AddAntiforgery(options =>
{
    options.HeaderName = "X-XSRF-TOKEN";
    options.RequireSsl = false;
    options.SuppressXFrameOptionsHeader = false;
});
```

This is in the controller:

```
[Authorize]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[HttpPost, Route("irrelevant")]
public IActionResult CalledByTheFront([FromBody] irrelevant)
{
    return Ok("irrelevant");
}
```

The cookies that I found in the browser
[image]

And the request :[image]

What am i doing wrong?
P.S. Also, do you know why the cookies in the browser only updates when the API restarts although every GET request has a Cookie in header?